Implementation of React-Datepicker component with Gutenberg in Wordpress
I'm working on a custom plugin that require an daterange picker control in a custom post type sidebar. Since I'd like to use Gutenberg for this (state that I'm quite a novice in React & Gutenberg as well) I opted to use the react-datepicker component ( - in particular, I'm using this: "Date Range using input with clear button").
Unlike other type of controls, such as inputs, checkbox, select etc, I'm quite struggling with this one, probably because of incorrect "show_in_rest" schema passed to the register_post_meta on the WordPress side, as well as how to deal with date value...
This is the meta registration I ended up:
register_post_meta(
    'post',
    '_my_metakey',
    [
        'type' => 'array',
        'single' => true,
        'default' => [null, null],
        'show_in_rest' => array(
            'schema' => array(
                'type'  => 'array',
                'items' => array(
                    'type' => 'object',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'startDate' => array('type' => 'object'),
                        'endDate' => array('type' => 'object'),
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),
    ]
);

(...but actually I've tried many different schemas - such as array with items etc...).
And this is the component I initially come out:
const MyDateRangePicker = ({ metaKey }) => {

    const { metaValue } = useSelect(
        (select) => {
            return {
                metaValue:
                    select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")[metaKey],
            };
        },
        [metaKey],
    );

    const { editPost } = useDispatch("core/editor");

    return (
            <DatePicker
                selectsRange={true}
                startDate={metaValue[0]}
                endDate={metaValue[0]}
                onChange={(newDates) => {
                    editPost(newDates);
                }}
                isClearable={true}
                showIcon
            />
    );
};
export default MyDateRangePicker;

But also in this case, I've also tried to use useState, passing my metaValue as default and create an handleChange function to wrap the editPost and passing the new value.
Then I include the control in sidebar like this:
<PanelRow>
    <MyDateRangePicker
        label={__("My daterangepicker", "text-domain")}
        metaKey="_my_metakey"
    />
</PanelRow>

I know I'm missing something basic here that I don't get.
Suggestion and hints on the right direction are more than welcome…
